# Memory optimization when finding the Cartesian product in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, memory-optimization

My function gets the Cartesian product of a list of lists of tuples.  The function is correctly producing the list of lists, but it's a memory hog (and leads to a MemoryError for large data sets, with the mapping/casting line probably the biggest culprit) and I have very little experience optimizing code with memory in mind.  The function is given here:

```
def make_ratio_groups(self):

    list_of_lists_of_tuples = []
    for part in whole:
        list_of_lists_of_tuples.append(part.list_of_tuples)

    all_groups = itertools.product(*list_of_lists_of_tuples)

    # Mapping and casting to list is necessary to put in the correct format for a subsequent function
    all_groups_list = list(map(list, all_groups))

    return all_groups_list
```

Is there a more memory-efficient way of doing this?  Thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Edit:  It's definitely the mapping and casting that's causing the problem.  I created a generator that handled the Cartesian product calculations and didn't see a big improvement in performance, so I tried profiling and found that the mapping/casting is definitely the issue.

Comment: Can you use a generator?  IE, what does the downstream processing look like?

Comment: I'm not familiar with generators (yet - am reading up now).  The returned object is subsequently mutated by two other functions; each time, some of the groups are removed from the object.  The object needs to be iterable.

Comment: If you post more of the code, you'll get better answers (and comments). For example, what is the definition of `whole`? — Also, definitely look into generators (i.e. `yield` instead of `return`), so that you don't have to keep everything in memory at once in the first place.

Comment: Generators look fantastic; thank you guys for pointing them out!  As for the rest,`part` and `whole` are complicated objects, but they have nothing to do with the code given here aside from demonstrating that the tuples in question are grabbed from a series of `part` objects.  That's not a memory-intensive chunk of code.  The only two pertinent sections IMO are the Cartesian product calculations and the subsequent mapping and casting to list.  The informal profiling I've done supports that.  I've been able to make a generator to replace `product`, but am not sure how to deal with map/cast.

Comment: I'm afraid your requirements as-is do not allow much memory optimization. You say that in the end you *need* the result to be a list of lists -- and that is what's really large. If you can't change that requirement (perhaps a good compromise would be an iterable of lists), then there's not much you can do.